# How to get selected item from select option using JQuery/JSon

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So i have this function: I want to get the selected item from my select but nothing works,I've tried using the selected function but still no luck, I think I'm missing something here.

```
function edit_fnc(x){
    var rowIndex    = $(x).parent().parent().index();
    groupingDataTable.edit_row(rowIndex);
    $('#lblStatus').html('');
      $.getJSON(backstage,
        {   
            action:RequestType.FetchBranch

        },
        function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(key,value) {
              $("#forbranch").append($("<option></option>").val(value.wid).text(value.name));

    });
        });
}
```

Comment: About `$("#forbranch").append($("<option></option>")` ??

Comment: yes, I want to display the selected item in select but i can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I mean you have a html syntax error. You missed greater sign for <option>;

Comment: Oh, sorry, I accidentally deleted it when arranging the spaces. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the HTML you're working with, but if you're using jQuery, we can using native HTML events and jQuery for a nice combo. Your select should be in a form element, so let's use the `'submit'` event and `$.serializeArray()` to grab the values in the form.

Here's some dummy HTML

```
<form>
  <select name="number">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
  <select name="letter">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Now some Javascript to grab the values:

```
$('form').submit(e => {
  let json = JSON.stringify($(e.currentTarget).serializeArray());
  $('#results').html(json);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's the codepen link http://codepen.io/alexsasharegan/pen/WRPjXK

That's not a specific answer, but I didn't fully understand the question. Throw up some follow up questions and I'll try helping further.

Comment: Hi, the function i posted was the function when i click my edit button, What i want to do is just get the selected item from my combobox. When i click the edit button. It's still displaying the default items (no selected) even when i add the ":selected" function from jquery. Maybe i'm misplacing it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little confused by convention. Usually an event handler takes either the short form `e` or the long form `event`. When wrapping HTML elements in jQuery, it's nice to prefix them with the dollar sign so we know they're jQuery instances of the element/s.

Assuming the select and button are not related, here's some HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
        <option value="theValue">the text</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The javascript

```
const $button   = $( 'button' );
const $mySelect = $form.find( 'form select' );

function getSelectedOption( event ) {
    const selectedValue     = $mySelect.val();
    const selectedInnerText = $mySelect.find( 'option:selected' ).text();

    console.log( { selectedValue, selectedInnerText } );
}

$button.click( getSelectedOption );
```

This should log `"theValue"` under `selectedValue` and `"the text"` under `selectedInnerText`.

Comment: Hopefully I'm getting closer to helping!

Comment: is this approach wrong ?

$("#forbranch").append($("<option />").val(value.wid).text(value.name).prop('selected',true));

Comment: Well, you said you wanted to get a selected option from the dom, but all your code seems to be replacing the dom (the initial post looks like it loads data from some server, and then appends new options).

Comment: Maybe add some html in here and kind of show from point a to point b what you need to get done exactly. I think I don't fully understand the goal maybe.

Comment: this is where i'm loading my data from. (FetchBranch):


case RequestType::FetchBranch:
        $resultSet = $priceRangeGroupRepository->fetchBranch();
        echo json_encode($resultSet);
            break;

Comment: then here:  

public function fetchBranch()
    {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT
                    `wid`,`name` from branch");
        $statement = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = [];
        $statement->execute($parameters);
        $dataSet = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $dataSet;

    }

Comment: Gotcha. So is the item you wish to display in the data loaded from the server? Are you trying to create select options out of the data loaded?

Comment: yes and yes. It loads the select options but it still shows the default. selections, with no selected item from the select list when i click the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
function edit_fnc( x ) {
    var rowIndex = $( x ).parent().parent().index();
    groupingDataTable.edit_row( rowIndex );
    $( '#lblStatus' ).html( '' );

    // you'll have to implement this
    let selected = getSelected( x );

    $.getJSON( backstage, { action: RequestType.FetchBranch }, function ( data ) {
        $.each( data, function ( key, value ) {
            $( "#forbranch" ).append(
                // and you'll have to figure out the correct equality check here
                `<option value="${value.wid}" ${this == selected ? 'selected' : ''}>${value.name}</option>`
            );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Okay, I'm not entirely sure of the mechanics of your function, but you just need to figure out how to do an equality check on your click event's value compared with what you load from the server.

Comment: P.S. Sorry if you can't use es6 template strings. It can get a bit tedious building the string with es5 javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the help!, How do i implement the getSelected ? do i make another function for it ?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, or just place the code directly inside your current function as they will always run together. It's just preference.

Comment: I've made a new function called getSelected and this is what i wrote:
function getSelected(){
    $('#forbranch').find(":selected").attr('value');
}
it still returns the new loaded data to me and not with the selected item?

Comment: Try and set up a codepen with your html and JavaScript. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to get.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I cant set up the interface but i can show you the codes here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgvZwG

no matter what i put inside the getSelected function, It still loads the the select dropdown with no selected item
here is a screenshot:
http://imgur.com/a/6xPSq